# Precision error when reading json file into CoreData

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

What I'm trying to do is reading an array of dictionaries from json file and store it in core data. The data is like:

```
[{"category": "A", "name": "x", "price": 7.95},
 {"category": "A", "name": "y", "price": 7.95},
 {"category": "B", "name": "z", "price": 8.95},
 ...]
```

And the codes to read it is like:

```
if let dataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("menu", ofType:"json") {
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: dataPath, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil) {
        if let menuData: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) {
            if let menuArray = menuData as? NSArray {
                for i in 0 ..< menuArray.count {
                    if let dish = menuArray[i] as? NSDictionary {

                        let newDishItem = DishItem(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)
                        newDishItem.name = dish["name"] as! String
                        newDishItem.category = dish["category"] as! String
                        newDishItem.price = dish["price"] as! Double

                    } else {print("element \(i) in array is not a dictionary! \n")}
                }
            } else {print("data loaded is not an array!\n")}
        } else {print("Unable to deserialize json data\n")}
    } else {print("Unable to load data!\n")}
} else { print("data file does not exist!\n") }
```

The problem is, when I read the stored prices back from core data, some prices become 8.9499999... when it should be 8.95, but some are good.

I thought it has something to do with storing numbers in binary data and tried to change all numbers in json to integers (8.95 to 895) and divide it by 100 when saving it to core data. However, this does not work. But I notice that if I don't divide it by 100 to leave them as integers, there's no such problem.

Any idea how to solve this? Suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, this is due to representing floating-point numbers in binary format. There's a limit to how accurate the numbers can be.

In most cases what you're seeing is acceptable and does not lead to errors.

If you want to be absolutely certain that you have 8.5, use the "decimal" type in the Core Data model editor. This will use `NSDecimalNumber` as the format, which is designed to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thanks a million : )

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot solve this problem since this has to do with the binary representation of a floating point number.

8.95 in binary is approximately 1000.11110011001100110011001100110011001... and doesn't stop there. A `Double` stores only 64 bits so the number cannot be converted to /stored as the original number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It helps a lot for a layman of computer science like me to understand the underlying mechanism!